# Left adjoint that preserves acyclic fibrations or weak equivalences

Tags: model-categories

Given a Quillen adjunction with left adjoint $L: \mathcal{C} \longrightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and right adjoint $R:\mathcal{D} \longrightarrow \mathcal{C}$, then we know that $L$ preserves cofibrations and acyclic cofibrations, and equivalently, $R$ preserves fibrations and acyclic fibrations.

My question is whether there is some condition on $R$ from which we can conclude that $L$ preserves weak equivalences or acyclic fibrations? In fact, the goal is to show that $L$ preserves cofibrant replacements.

I am in the situation where $R$ is fully faithful and preserves weak equivalences, fibrations and cofibrations. Do these properties also translate to $L$?

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: We may be in the situation of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.  Why exactly do you want L to preserve cofibrant replacements?  Could you provide the context for this problem?  What is L and R in your case?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I wasn't aware of XY problem, but yes probably. I have a morphism of operads P -->Q and it induces a Quillen adjunction between the respective algebra cats Alg(P) |- Alg(Q). The right adjoint has a really easy description for which I can prove the above properties. The left adjoint has a more difficult description, especially cohomologically. However, I do really expect the left adjoint to preserve weak equivalences. P. Tamaroff provides some criterion for when this happens for morphisms of operads, unfortunately I do not expect this to be fulfilled. Thanks for considering tho!